# C code to simulate parabolic trajectory of launched object terminates early

Tags: c, output

This program simulates the parabolic trajectory of an object launched at an angle at a fixed vertical and horizontal velocity. It outputs data in coordinates displayed in the terminal console.

However, the program outputs data only up to the second line and terminate, so there must be an error somewhere in the code. I cannot identify the error so I am requesting for help!

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(void) {
 float lvelox;
 float lveloy;
 float xcord;
 float ycord;
 int stepcount;
 int step = 0;

 /* Initializing velocity */
 {
   printf("Enter the initial h velocity of the ball:\n");
   scanf("%f", &lvelox);
   printf("Enter the initial v velocity of the ball:\n");
   scanf("%f", &lveloy);
 }

 /* Obtain number of steps */
 {
   printf("Enter the number of steps wanted:\n");
   scanf("%d", &stepcount);
 }

 /* formula for calculating initial position */
   if ( step == 0 )
   {
   xcord = 0;
   ycord = 0;
   step = step + 1;
   printf("\n");
   printf("xcord, ycord, step\n");
   printf("\n");
   printf("%f, ", xcord);
   printf("%f, ", ycord);
   printf("%d\n", step);
   }

 /* Loop method */
   if ( step < stepcount )
   {
   lveloy = lveloy - 9.81;
   xcord = xcord + lvelox;
   ycord = ycord + lveloy;
   step = step + 1;
   printf("%f, ", xcord);
   printf("%f, ", ycord);
   printf("%d\n", step);

   if ( ycord < 0 )
   {
   lveloy = (lveloy * -1);
   lveloy = lveloy - 9.81;
   xcord = xcord + lvelox;
   ycord = ycord + lveloy;
   step = step + 1;
   printf("%f, ", xcord);
   printf("%f, ", ycord);
   printf("%d\n", step);
   }
   }

   if (step >= stepcount)
   {
       return 0;
   }

 }
```

Comment: Side-note: Your `printf`s are overly verbose. You can, e.g., write this: `printf("%f, %f, %d\n", xcord, ycord, step);`.

Comment: Also, `if (step == 0)` is redundant, since `step` is guaranteed to be zero at that point.

Comment: One more side-Note read: [**Indenting C Programs**](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/indent_c.html)

Comment: But wait, there's more: `x = x + 1` should be `x++`, and `x = x + y` should be `x += y`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a loop instead of `if`, In your code:

```
 if ( step < stepcount )
```

Should be:

```
 while ( step < stepcount )
```

Comment: you can remove: `if (step >= stepcount)`  the code will work find

Answer (score 1):

Your "loop method" isn't a loop! It's an if-statement. Change it to a for-loop that increments `step` and perhaps that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood the way loops are constructed. You've written this:

```
if (step == 0) {
    // Starting code
    ⋮
}
if (step < stepcount) {
    // Loop code
    ⋮
}
if (step >= stepcount) {
    // Finishing code
    ⋮
}
```

And you seem to have assumed that something will automatically loop over these tests. This won't happen. Rewrite the above as follows:

```
// Starting code
⋮
for (step = 0; step < stepcount; ++step) {
    // Loop code
    ⋮
}
// Finishing code
⋮
```

Note that this code automatically increments `step` on each pass, so you'll have to rethink how the loop code updates it. You seem to conditionally update it twice, which I don't fully understand, so I hesitate to prescribe a specific change.